# WSFederationConstants.Parameters.Result equivalent in WIF .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, wif

I am trying to convert some code written in ASP.NET (with .NET version 3.5) that is using Windows Identity Foundation in MVC 5 that is using .NET 4.5

I found some useful information on msdn [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157089.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157091.aspx).

I haven't yet found equivalent of `WSFederationConstants.Parameters.Result` in .NET 4.5

What can be used to replace that?